# Troubleshooting the interop word

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop

I have got a requirement to read the pages of the word files and PDF files while uploading in  C#. I have searched it online and got a method. It just works fine at local but it is not working at server.I searched for the problem. I was getting this exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
>          at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

I have also found it's solution and it was basically related to Permissions on server.

I set all the rights but still it is throwing same exception. I am not finding any way to resolve this problem.

I am using following Code:

```
 var application = new Application();
 var document = application.Documents.Open(path);
 var numberOfPages = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);

 result = numberOfPages;
 object saveOption = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
 object originalFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
 object routeDocument = false;
 document.Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

 application.Quit();
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);
```

And this is the DLL that I am using from Com components in Dot Net project(Mvc 4.0)

> Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll, v12.0.0.0

I am having MS office 2007 installed at my local machine but server has 2013 Ms office. Can it be a something related to the error.

Comment: what is the bitness of your application, ms office 2007 and ms office 2013?

Comment: is suffering same problem.some time it also works but not always